# Dynamically increase the Height of JTable based on the Number of Rows Inserted

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have a JTable with fixed size that I want to load all my data on.

```
table.setPreferredSize(1400, 600);
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
while(resultSet.next()){        
   model.addRow(row);
}
```

But when I scroll down the table, not all the rows are visible. Rows that are greater than the height of JTable are out of view.

I tried to set the Height of table to 3000 and data becomes visible. But I only want my table to have a fixed height and use scroll to navigate through the rest of data that are out of view from the table.

How can I dynamically set the Height of the JTable based on number of rows inserted to the table model?

Comment: override setPreferredScrollableViewportSize instead of setPreferredSize (hasn't nothing with your question, is about design and correct method),

Answer (score 0):

Add the table in the scroll pane, it will allow to scroll through the table contents as needed. Add this scroll pane to your JPanel that is being displayed.

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
```